# Smartphone can't connect to AccessPoint. NETWORK_SELECTION_DISABLED_ASSOCIATION_REJECTION

Tags: wi-fi

I have a Epson TM-P20 mobile printer device, that offers a mode in which it launches a WiFi Hotspot. The HotSpot always uses the same name and the same passphrase. For some reason, my Smartphone can't connect to this HotSpot. After trying different devices, I figured that my Samsung Tablet connects without a problem.

I have tried connecting with a Samsung S21+ on API Level 33 and a Samsung S20 on API level 32 (I think). Trying to connect fails almost instantly with connection failed. Getting desperate I tried using a Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE on API level 32, and it worked pretty much instantly. I then tried playing around with WiFi settings on my phone but with no success. I then tried to connect via code, hoping to get some kind of exception but no luck.

I am 100% positive that the password is correct. I turned WiFi off and on, rebooted the phone and so on. Also my phone (or phones even) do not have any trouble connecting with any other HotSpot or WiFi.

What I think could be an issue, is that he HotSpot (for obvious reasons) does not provide internet connection. It is just a simple access point to pair with the printer. Also the AccessPoint uses only 2.4GHz. What is also worth mentioning, the HotSpot the printer provides can't be configured. It uses WPA-PSK (AES) encryption and a very simple passphrase.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the issue or how to debug further?

Update: I found a setting for extended WiFi logging. Now I can see that the desired WiFi has an error in the list of available WiFis saying "NETWORK_SELECTION_TEMPORARY_DISABLED" before the first failed attempt, and "NETWORK_SELECTION_DISABLED_ASSOCIATION_REJECTION" after it failed to connect.

Does anyone know this issue and how to get around it?

Comment: Searching for "wifi ASSOCIATION REJECTION" you will find a lot of topics in xda dev forums for the last 8 years, unfortunately none contains a real description why it happens and how to solve it. It is even possible that this is a technical incompatibility between different Wifi chipsets which would explain why some devices work and other don't.